# Phidget RFID Not attached (ANDROID and PHIDGET)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, rfid

I am currently having problems in Eclipse, even though my Phidget RFID is attached the the device (emulator) does not, I have run it in normal Java classes that are not android related and it works. I have restarted a number of times.

Below is the log cat report:

```
01-06 13:10:18.984: W/System.err(623): PhidgetException 5 (Phidget not physically attached.)
01-06 13:10:19.004: W/System.err(623):  at com.phidgets.RFIDPhidget.setAntennaOn(Native Method)
01-06 13:10:19.016: W/System.err(623):  at myFood.myFood.AddFood.onCreate(AddFood.java:35)
01-06 13:10:19.034: W/System.err(623):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-06 13:10:19.034: W/System.err(623):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-06 13:10:19.034: W/System.err(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
01-06 13:10:19.044: W/System.err(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-06 13:10:19.054: W/System.err(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-06 13:10:19.054: W/System.err(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-06 13:10:19.054: W/System.err(623):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-06 13:10:19.074: W/System.err(623):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-06 13:10:19.074: W/System.err(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-06 13:10:19.085: W/System.err(623):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 13:10:19.085: W/System.err(623):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-06 13:10:19.085: W/System.err(623):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-06 13:10:19.094: W/System.err(623):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-06 13:10:19.103: W/System.err(623):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Below is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.phidgets.InterfaceKitPhidget;
import com.phidgets.Phidget;
import com.phidgets.PhidgetException;
import com.phidgets.RFIDPhidget;
import com.phidgets.event.TagGainEvent;
import com.phidgets.event.TagGainListener;


public class AddFood  extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    RFIDPhidget rfid;

    static String x ="NULL";
    int i = 0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addfood);
        final TextView mytext=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.widget96);


try
{

        com.phidgets.usb.Manager.Initialize(this);
        rfid = new RFIDPhidget();
        rfid.setAntennaOn(true);
        rfid.setLEDOn(true);

        //Begin the TagGained event, allowing for users to read the RFID values



        rfid.addTagGainListener(new TagGainListener()
        {

            public void tagGained(TagGainEvent oe)
            {


                Object y = (oe.getValue());
                x= y.toString();
            }
        });
        rfid.open(34235);


        long StartTime,RunTime;
        StartTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        do{

            RunTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (x.equals("NULL")) {

                //Continue waiting for input
                }
            else

            StartTime = 10000; //Overload the result so the loop ends
        }
        while (RunTime-StartTime<5000);

        rfid.close();
        com.phidgets.usb.
        Manager.Uninitialize();

}
catch(PhidgetException e)
{

    e.printStackTrace();
}

        Button mybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        mybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {






        }


        });

}

}
```

and my Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="myFood.myFood"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" />
        <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".myFood"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
   <activity android:name=".AddFood" android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
</activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

If anyone has any experience with PHIDGETS or anything like this all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Phidget WebService I changed the `open()` to `open(IP,PORT)`. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using rfid.openAny();
and also insert the ipaddress on the machine the phidget is plugged into

e.g rfid.openAny("192.168.10.1", 34325);
That way your android device can read and interact with it over the network